# error 404 for rest service in netbeans, using tomcat7 and java JDK 8

Tags: java, rest, netbeans, java-8, jersey

i am using netbeans ide 8.0.2. I created a java webb app and i am trying to make some rest services. If i use java jdk 7 everything works fine. Now i am trying to use JDK 8 since is needed and when i compile i get the warning:

*\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class*

and when i call the service i always get error 404.

I am not using maven and in the default libs i have JAX-RS 2.0 and Jersey 2.5.1 (libs).

Any idea what the error is about? I have checked previous similar posts but no help.

Thank you in advance,
Galateia

Comment: error sayinh clearly that its not able to find `javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar` , you need to provide this in your lib folder.

Comment: i have tried that but i still got the same error

Comment: i fixed it by editing the properties of tomcat in netbeans: i chose the jdk 1.8  as a default platform for tomcat